# How to prove that in a Kähler manifold without boundary $\Omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \Omega$ is closed but not exact?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact Kähler manifold without boundary.

1. How can I show that the volume form  $$ \Omega^{m} = \Omega \wedge
       \cdots \wedge \Omega $$ where we have the wedge of $m$ $\Omega$s is
   closed but not exact for the case that the complex dimension of $M$
   is $m$. The hint I am given is to use Stoke's theorem.
2. Also, what happens with the cohomology of this system?

Comment: I want to use the hint, i.e. Stoke's theorem but I don't know how to integrate this wedge product in order to reach some conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Suppose $\Omega^m$ is exact; what does Stokes' Theorem say about the integral $\int_M \Omega^m$?

Comment: That's what I thought too. So the Kahler condition is irrelevant no? (You just need to have a volume form on a compact manifold without boundary).

Comment: Yes, that's right. Presumably the problem as stated comes from a text/course dedicated to Kahler geometry.

Comment: Indeed, this is from Nakahara's Geometry, Topology and Physics. Well, if $\Omega^m$ is exact then we can write it as $\Omega^m = dY^m$. Then Stoke's theorem would say $\int_M \Omega^m  = \int_M dY^m = \int_{\partial M} Y$. But we said that $M$ has no boundary. So, ok, I think I am confused now since $\Omega^m$ is not supposed to be exact.

Comment: Right, since $M$ has no boundary, that integral is zero. Now, what can we say about the integral $\int_M \Omega^m$ given that $\Omega^m$ is a volume form?

Comment: I am not quite sure what we can say about it. This is where I am confused about. I do not follow your thought. A) I am not sure what this integration to zero means and B) I am not sure why I have to assume that I can write $\Omega = dY$ since the exercise clearly says that $\Omega$ is not exact.

Comment: For (B), the tack is that you assume $\Omega$ is exact and then show that this leads to a contradiction. Separately from the issue of exactness, what happens when we integrate a volume form over a manifold?

Comment: Wait a minute! By Stoke's theorem an exact form would integrate to zero as above. But $\Omega$ is a volume form it cannot be integrated to zero thus it is not exact although it is closed. Is this the answer?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. In particular, there is a closed-but-not-exact $n$-form, so what can we say about the top de Rham cohomology, $H^{2m}(M)$?

Comment: Hi @Travis, I am not sure. The de Rham cohomology is the closed over the exact forms so, this m-form does not fit in there. Other than that I am not sure what I could say thought

Comment: Since there is an element that is closed by not exact, the space $Z$ of exact $2m$-forms is a proper subspace of the space $B$ of closed forms. So, what we can say about the dimension of the quotient $H^{2 m}(M) := Z^{2m}(M) / B^{2m}(M)$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my early thought.

If $M$ is a Kahler manifold, then if $N \subset M$ is a compact complex submanifold without boundary of complex dimension $k$, then the chomology class of $\omega^{k}$ of $H^{2k}(M, \mathbb{R})$ and the homology class of $N$ in $H_{2k}(M, \mathbb{R})$ are non-zero.